# Find last row of non empty cell using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is little weird to ask but what i want is, identify last row of a non-empty cell in a column. I know Match and Row function but it will not help here.

Important:

1. Remember range selection is entire column `A:A`
2. Only Excel formula, no VBA or macro

Data:

[image: "Data"]

Comment: Does the range contain text values, numerics, or a mixture of both? Depending on the answer, zipa's solution below (which is extremely resource-heavy, having to process all 1,048,576 cells within the column) could potentially be vastly improved in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))
```

Comment: brother, it gives me last value not row.

Answer (score -1):

select the whole row and HOLD **Ctrl + DOWN ARROW KEY** to find out non-empty cell in a row